# AppWindow MoveAndResize DPI: wrong window size with multple displays and different scale

Tags: c#, winui-3

I'm trying to write a program that displays a window on the screen where the mouse is. The window is displayed when a keyboard shortcut is pressed. For this, I use the MoveAndResize method provided in AppWindow and a DisplayArea.

My 2 displays don't have the same scale : one is 125% and the other one is 150%. When I hit the hotkey on the first screen, the size of the window is correct. If I move my mouse to the second screen and press the hotkey, the size of the window is wrong. But if I press the hotkey again, the size of the window is correct. Here is what I'm using:

```
Windows.Graphics.RectInt32 rect = new()
{
    X = (displayArea.WorkArea.Width / 2) - (_wndWidth / 2),
    Y = (displayArea.WorkArea.Height / 3) - (_wndHeight / 2),
    Height = _wndHeight,
    Width = _wndWidth
};

_appWindow.MoveAndResize(rect, displayArea);
_appWindow.Show();
_appWindow.MoveInZOrderAtTop();
```

I read [here](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/2731) that AppWindow.Resize() requires the size to be already scaled using DPI of the monitor. It does not used the device independent values as WPF does.

```
GetDpiForMonitor(monitor, Windows.Win32.UI.HiDpi.MONITOR_DPI_TYPE.MDT_EFFECTIVE_DPI, out uint dpiX, out uint dpiY);
var dpi = dpiX / 96d;
```

Using GetDpiForMonitor gives me the dpi of the monitor but even if I provide the "correct" width (int)(_wndWidth * dpi), the size is still incorrect when the window is displayed. The size is fixed when the window appears the second time on the same screen. If I switch back to the primary display and press the hotkey, the size is wrong but a second run gives me the correct size.

Do you have any idea on how to solve this problem?

Thanks

**Update**

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
using Microsoft.UI;
using Microsoft.UI.Windowing;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using WinRT.Interop;

namespace WindowMove
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty window that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private ObservableCollection<DisplayArea> _displayAreas;
        private DisplayAreaWatcher _watcher;
        private int _index = 0;

        private readonly AppWindow _appWindow;
        private readonly int _wndWidth = 1024;
        private readonly int _wndHeight = 300;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            
            _appWindow = GetAppWindowForCurrentWindow();
            _appWindow.SetPresenter(AppWindowPresenterKind.CompactOverlay);

            InitDisplayArea();

            MoveWindow();
        }

        private void InitDisplayArea()
        {
            _displayAreas = new ObservableCollection<DisplayArea>();
            _watcher = DisplayArea.CreateWatcher();
            _watcher.Added += Display_Added;
            _watcher.Start();
        }

        private void Display_Added(DisplayAreaWatcher sender, DisplayArea args)
        {
            _displayAreas.Add(args);
        }

        private AppWindow GetAppWindowForCurrentWindow()
        {
            IntPtr hWnd = WindowNative.GetWindowHandle(this);
            WindowId myWndId = Win32Interop.GetWindowIdFromWindow(hWnd);
            return AppWindow.GetFromWindowId(myWndId);
        }

        private void MoveWindow_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MoveWindow();
        }

        private void HideAndShow_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            HideAndShow();
        }

        private void ResizeWindowSameScreen_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MoveWindow(true);
        }

        private void MoveWindow(bool isSameScreen = false)
        {
            if (!isSameScreen)
            {
                _index++;
            }
            
            DisplayArea area = _displayAreas[_index % 2];

            Windows.Graphics.RectInt32 rect = new()
            {
                X = (area.WorkArea.Width - _wndWidth) / 2,
                Y = (area.WorkArea.Height / 3) - (_wndHeight / 2),
                Height = _wndHeight,
                Width = _wndWidth
            };

            Debug.WriteLine($"Window position: [X: {rect.X}, Y: {rect.Y}, W: {rect.Width}, H: { rect.Height}]");
            _appWindow.MoveAndResize(rect, area);

            _appWindow.Show();
            _appWindow.MoveInZOrderAtTop();
        }

        private async void HideAndShow()
        {
            _appWindow.Hide();
            await Task.Delay(2000);
            _appWindow.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Window
    x:Class="WindowMove.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:WindowMove"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Button x:Name="myButton" Click="MoveWindow_Click">Switch</Button>
        <Button x:Name="resizeSameScreen" Click="ResizeWindowSameScreen_Click">Resize on same screen</Button>
        <Button x:Name="hideAndShow" Click="HideAndShow_Click">Hide / Show</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**app.manifest**

```
<application xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <windowsSettings>
      <dpiAwareness xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2016/WindowsSettings">PerMonitorV2</dpiAwareness>
    </windowsSettings>
  </application>
```

Comment: I have an idea on how to solve this problem: post a complete simple reproducing code somewhere https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example what you currently show is not enough, devil hides in details

Comment: Is your app high DPI aware?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hidpi/high-dpi-desktop-application-development-on-windows

Comment: It is recommended that desktop applications be updated to use per-monitor DPI awareness mode, allowing them to immediately render correctly whenever the DPI changes.

Comment: Hi, I edited the initial post and I added a full example. To see the problem, click on Switch button (the window will move on your second screen) then click on the "Resize on same screen" button and you will see that the width of the window will be adjusted to the correct size. Regarding the DPI aware, the app.manifest file contains the PerMonitorV2 value.